# JQuery animation makes page jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I found a bit of script to make a div `loginform` slide in from the edge of the back, and back out, on different clicks, of `loginshow` and `loginhide`. Also a bit of script to make `topbar` (containing the 'show' button) and `loginform` to scroll down when I scroll down the page.

My intent is for `loginform` to be hidden and shown from anywhere, so you do not have to scroll to the top of the page to access the fields/elements on that div.

However whenever I click `loginshow` or `loginhide`, the page jumps back to the top as the `loginform` animation runs.

This is the script

```
var main = function() {
$('#loginshow').click(function(){
    $('#topbar').animate({
        left: '245px'
    }, 200);
    $('#loginform').delay(100).animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 200);    
    $('#loginhide').delay(200).animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 100);
});
$('#loginhide').click(function(){
    $('#loginhide').animate({
        left: '-80px'
    }, 200)
    $('#loginform').delay(200).animate({
        left: '-240px'
    }, 200)
    $('#topbar').delay(300).animate({
        left: '5px'
    }, 200);
})
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#loginform').css({
        top: scrollPos
    });
    $('#topbar').css({
        top: scrollPos
    });
}).scroll();
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

How can I stop the `loginshow` and `loginhide` functions make the page jump back up?
Thanks for any help, I have only just started with javascript yesterday.

Comment: If you click submit buttons or links, you need to use preventDefault() to stop the page from reloading

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the scripting and HTML? Where are those elements located in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried using jQuery [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)?

```
    $('#loginshow').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
// Your code here
    });
```

Comment: Nah - I closed it as duplicate anyway :)

Comment: @mplungjan okey this is more adequate. thank you